# Does every algebra have a unique decomposition?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

This is from pages 8-9 of *Probability-1* by Shiryaev.

**Background:**

We have a finite sample space $\Omega$. If we partition $\Omega$ into sets $D_1, \dots, D_n$ which are all non-empty, then the set of all $D_1, \dots, D_n$, their various unions, and the empty set form what is called the algebra induced by $\mathcal D = \{ D_1, \dots, D_n \}$. We label the algebra as $\alpha (\mathcal D)$.

(An algebra $\mathcal A$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$ that contains $\Omega$, and if $A, B \in \mathcal A$, then $A \cap B, A \cup B$, and $A \setminus B$ are all in $\mathcal A$.)

I am trying to understand why there is a one-to-one correspondence between the algebras of $\Omega$ and the decompositions of $\Omega$. I think that any one decomposition cannot produce more than one algebra. (You can't get two different results by unioning the same building blocks.) What I need to do is show that given some algebra $\mathcal B$, there is a unique decomposition $\mathcal D$ such that $\alpha (\mathcal D) = \mathcal B$.

**Attempt:**

Shiryaev says that you consider $D \in \mathcal B$ such that for all $B \in \mathcal B$, either $D \cap B = \emptyset$ or $D \cap B = D$, and if you do this as many times as possible, then you recover the decomposition $D_1, \dots, D_n$ of $\Omega$ that gave rise to $\mathcal B$. I don't understand this.

I think I can show that if $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two such sets, then if they intersect at all, they must coincide. To see this, assume that $D_1$ and $D_2$ satisfy Shiryaev's conditions, and that $D_1 \cap D_2 \neq \emptyset$. We then must have $D_1 \cap D_2 = D_1 = D_2$.

Assuming that is correct, then all that's left to do is show that $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n D_i = \Omega$. I think it's pretty clear that $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n D_i \subseteq \Omega$ because all the $D_i$'s are elements of $\mathcal{B}$. I just don't know how to show that $\Omega \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^n D_i$.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

I also need to specify that the sets $D$ from Shiryaev's method are non-empty.

**Edit 2:**

Still trying to figure out how to show that $\Omega \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^n D_i$. Consider $\omega \in \Omega$. We know there is at least one $B \in \mathcal B$ such that $\omega \in B$. If the set of all $B \in \mathcal B$ containing $\omega$ is $B_1, \dots, B_k$, then consider $\bigcap_{i = 1}^k B_i$. We want to show that this is one of the elements in the set $\mathcal D = \{ D_1, \dots, D_n \}$.

Let $\bigcap_{i = 1}^k B_i = D$. We see that $B_j \cap D = D$ for $j = 1, \dots, k$. Now consider all the other $B \in \mathcal B$, i.e. the ones not containing $\omega$. For any such $B$, it is clear that $B \cap D \neq D$, since $\omega \notin B$. Therefore, if my strategy is going to succeed, I need to show that $B \cap D = \emptyset$.

I'm stuck again. Also, I've realized that once I have a decomposition $\mathcal D$, I'm still not done; I need to show that $\alpha (\mathcal D) = \mathcal B$.

**Edit 3:**

Thinking about my last edit, I am not convinced now that it is true that $B \cap D = \emptyset$. Couldn't it be possible that $B \cap D = B$? (This could only happen if $B$ were not a member of the decomposition $\mathcal D$.) I am pretty sure that $B \cap D \neq D$, though.

**Edit 4:**

The following links seem pretty relevant, but I haven't figured it out yet.

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181555/number-of-elements-in-a-finite-sigma-algebra), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143796/number-of-sigma-algebra-on-the-finite-set), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451976/number-of-sigma-algebras-on-finite-sets).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that $d\in\bigcap\{B\in\mathcal{B}\mid d\in B\}$ for all $d\in D$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not quite sure I follow. Is it that if there were some non-empty $C \subseteq \Omega$ that did not intersect with any of the $D_1, \dots, D_n$, then we could let $D_{n + 1} = C$?

Comment: Not quite.  You need to make sure $C$ is minimal, just as all the $D_i$'s.

Comment: I'm not sure why I used a set $C$. I am getting confused between the elements of $\Omega$ and those of $\mathcal B$. I will try again: consider $\omega \in \Omega$. We know $\omega \in B$ for at least one $B \in \mathcal B$. If $\omega \notin D_i$ for all $D_i$, then we could let $D_{n + 1} = \{ \omega \}$. But we already assumed that Shiryaev's procedure was followed as many times as possible, so we must have $\omega \in \bigcup D_i$.

Comment: No, you don't know $\{\omega\}\in\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: But I know that $\Omega \in \mathcal B$, so clearly $\omega \in B$ for at least one $B \in \mathcal B$.

Comment: You can't "let $D_{n+1}=\{\omega\}$" because there is no reason why the smallest $B\in\mathcal{B}$ containing $\omega$ is a singleton.

Comment: Okay, I think I forgot that every $D_i \in \mathcal B$. Have I made any use of your hint? I don't understand it. Every element in any $D_i$ is in the intersection of all $B \in \mathcal B$ that contain that element.